# ZF 2.4 - controller - alternative for init()?

Tags: zend-framework2

I've this two lines on all the action() in the controller so I want to move it to init() so it will get called each time. It doesn't work so I tried __construct and it won't work as it says "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null"

Maybe that can be done in factory and you still call getServiceLocator in factory class? If I can do it within controller that will be even better as that's less step to do and is that possible to do it in controller so every action will have that?

```
    $view_helper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager');
    $view_helper->get('headScript')->appendFile(....);
```

Comment: So what is the reason why you are adding a headscript file from within your controllers and not from within the layout or other view file. And need to check some things before appending the file, create a viewHelper who helps you with this job to keep your views clean and neat?

Comment: Because I've many controllers and each one has many actions. I've js files that not all controllers required so shouldn't put it in the layout. Then I've many actions using the same js file. If I need to change one js file then I can change it in one place instead of many view files which is much better.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that I can do what I mentioned instead putting the same js file over and over again on different views. It will take time if I need to point to a different js file.

Comment: In that case go ahead and do what you suggested within your question. And inject the file within the ControllerFactory. The ViewHelper is a container instance so it should be possible, but you might want to check whether you want to append or use an offset if it has any other dependencies like jQuery for example. Not sure whether the files within the layout are basically loaded first or that your Controllers appendFile will be the first file. But a simple trial and error will do. Notice: you can also do it within your module's bootstrap if you want the whole module.

Answer (score 0):

Only two solutions exist:

1. You can do an abstract controller, and use the `viewhelpermanager` as dependency in your constructor. This means you will need to pass the `viewhelpermanager` in all the subclasses factories and not forget to call the parent construct and so on when creating the object.
2. You can use a delegator in the service manager and an abstract controller that contains a `setViewHelperManager` method and a `viewhelpermanager` (or worst, a trait :) and a ViewHelperManagerAwareInterface and an initializer), and do a "soft dependency", but that's a wrong way to do things in terms of maintenance (code readability).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your own view helper and make that include the js file(s). You can then use this in all the view.phtml files that require these files. If you need to change/add/remove js files then just do this in your view helper, obviously this change will reflect in all your views that use it.

This keeps the view stuff away from your controller.

Hope this helps.